# Linkedin doesn't display article description after sharing by customized URL

Tags: linkedin-api

I don't know if anyone else experienced the same problem, but I just don't know why article description is not visible on my feed page after sharing.
I used these recommendations for customized URL sharing: 
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

i.e. my link looks like this:

> https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn

If you follow this link, you'll see that the summary ("My favorite developer program") is visible in the preview. However, this summary is not visible in my feed after sharing. 
The same happens if I use  tag within page markup instead of specifying  "summary" directly in URL

I'll be very grateful for your advice.

Comment: might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189486/linkedin-sharing-url-summary-not-appearing (or vice versa)

Answer (score 3):

You can only choose one option:

- Indicate an image with an `og:image` tag, and your image will display.
- Don't indicate an image, and then your description will display.

Do you want ***both an image and a description*** to display?  Currently just not possible.  Maybe put the text of the description into the image?  I have no idea, it would just be nice if they made their API work according to their own documentation.

Source: [**Arguing with LinkedIn Support for 2 Weeks**](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-broken-ticket.html).